# How to async properly in a foor loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I am trying to store some data into a group of PDF files using Puppeteer. But when I try to run this code my app is freezing and I assume I am doing something wrong with the async and await code. It seems to be working properly, the documents are created properly in the folder of the project, but at some point node crashes and I must reboot my PC.

```
 const path = require("path");
 const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
 const fs = require('fs');

 for (let index = 0; index < documentsToPDF.length; index ++) {
        const result = await generatePDF(documentsToPDF[index]);
        await createAndSavePDFInFile(documentsToPDF[index], result);
      }

async function generatePDF(browser, numdoc) {
  const filePage = await browser.newPage();
  filePage.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  await filePage.goto(renderPath(numdoc), {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });
  return filePage.pdf({
    format: "A4",
  });
}

async function createAndSavePDFInFile(numdoc, result) {
  console.log(result);
  if(result) {
    return fs.writeFile(
      path.join(__dirname, `../results/result-${numdoc}.pdf`),
      result,
      (error, result) => {
        if(error) console.log('error', err);
        else console.log(`PDF result-${numdoc}.pdf `);
      }
    ); 
  } else {
    console.log(`numdoc `, numdoc, ' could not be saved into pdf');
  }

}
```

Thanks for your help, I'm new to node and I'm learning :)

EDIT:

This loop now is working fine

```
for (let index = 0; index < documentsToPDF.length; index += 1) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteerParams);
    const result = await generatePDF(browser,documentsToPDF[index]);
    await createAndSavePDFInFile(documentsToPDF[index], result);
    browser.close();
    console.log('Exp: ', documentsToPDF[index], ' SUCCESS');
}
```

But can I do something like this?

```
   const pdfPromises = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < documentsToPDF.length; index += 1) {
    pdfPromises.push(createPdf(puppeteer, puppeteerParams, documentsToPDF[index]))
  }

await Promise.all(pdfPromises);


async function createPdf(puppeteer, puppeteerParams, numexp) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(puppeteerParams);
  const result = await generatePDF(browser, numexp);
  await createAndSavePDFInFile(numexp, result);
  browser.close();
  console.log('Exp: ', numexp, ' SUCCESS');
}
```

I've tried and it returns this error:

MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 event listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Comment: You're returning the callback version of `fs.writeFile` -- use `fs.promises`. A major red flag is using `async` on a function but never `await`ing anything in it. Also, `const filePage = await browser.newPage();` never gets closed, that's a memory leak, so Node won't exit cleanly. It's a good idea to show complete code including where you've imported these functions.

Comment: It works! Now I am using `fs.promises.writeFile` and I have changed the loop. I edit the loop in the post to show the new changes.

Is there a way to improve the code inside the loop? For example, doing all the awaits into a single Promise?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Since it doesn't look like order matters here, instead of awaiting each promise, I tend to make an array of promises then I can do `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)` or `Promise.allSettled(arrayOfPromises)`. That way all the promises can all start at the same time (if you have the bandwidth) rather than wait one by one.

Comment: I've tried `pdfPromises.push(createPdf(puppeteer, puppeteerParams, documentsToPDF[index]))` and then `await Promise.all(pdfPromises);` but I get `MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 event listeners added` and the computer freezes.